# Best way to compare projects on Enterprise Architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

I want to know if there is a way to see the changes I made it to a linked files when I compare a project against a base line or a file to file.

I tried the compare utility from base line and file to file comparassion, and its works, if I add a linked file to x component or edit an existing one, it shows that there is  change, but not in the best o most readeable way.

There is another way or tool to acomplished that?

Thank you.

pd_ sorry for my bad english

Comment: What do you mean by "linked files"? You want EA to check the content of the linked files being changed??

Comment: yes, I made a simple test, where I compare a project against a base line, and I just add a linked document to an actor component and the diff tools shows me that I made a change to the actor but not what was the change [link](http://i.imgur.com/gik8y3e.png), in larger projects, with a lot of linked documents, I want to track which one had change... sorry if i am missing something or this a dumb question :)

Comment: EA will at best compare the file name, but not it's contents. You can do as Geert suggests in your own comparison engine.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can

- Write your own comparison engine
- Export the comparison xml and use that to present it in a way you like it better
- Use [LieberLiebers Lemontree](http://www.lieberlieber.com/lemontree/en/)